# Copy paste cells using VBA from two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code I have below, it works just not sure why when it copies over into the second and third column it moves down a row.

```
Dim shB As Worksheet, shPM As Worksheet, lastRowB As Long, lastRowPM As Long
 Dim shC As Worksheet, shD As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim eRow As Long

 Set shB = Worksheets("Billable")
 Set shPM = Worksheets("PM_Forecast")

 lastRowB = Worksheets("Billable").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 ''Loop will run from row 6 to the last row (Row 6 is the first row in table)
 For i = 6 To lastRowB
    ''Check Billable requests first
    If shB.Cells(i, 15).Value = "Detailed Estimate Submitted" Then
        ''Copy over ID reference
        shB.Cells(i, 2).Copy
        eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        shB.Paste Destination:=shPM.Cells(eRow + 1, 1)
        ''Copy over title
        shB.Cells(i, 3).Copy
        eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        shB.Paste Destination:=shPM.Cells(eRow + 1, 2)
        ''Copy over Effort
        shB.Cells(i, 9).Copy
        eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        shB.Paste Destination:=shPM.Cells(eRow + 1, 3)
```

End If
Next

This is a pic of the results, perhaps someone can tell me where I went wrong.

[image]

Comment: `eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`... you're always getting the last row from column A, but probably need to get it from the column in question (the one you're pasting to)... or just get it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not calculate `eRow` each time (based on A:A column) when try pasting to the next columns.

Use `shB.Paste Destination:=shPM.Cells(eRow , 2)` (not `eRow + 1`) for each iteration.

Otherwise, the new added value in column A:A will add another row to `eRow`...

Or calculate the last row for each column:

`eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` and `eRow = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row`, according to the column where you intend to copy the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using `Union` and placing the next empty cell variable inside the `If` Statement so it gets recalculate each loop.

```
'Define your sheet variables. `ThisWorkbook` means, the workbook in which the excel code is in. 
Dim wsSrce As Worksheet: Set wsSrce = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Billable")
Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PM_Forecast")

'Define the last row variable in the source sheet
Dim lRowSrce As Long: lRowSrce = wsSrce.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With wsSrce
        For i = 6 To lRowSrce

            'test each row for the data in Column O.
            If .Cells(i, 15).Value = "Detailed Estimate Submitted" Then

                'Define the next empty row variable in the destination sheets, within your IF statement
                Dim NxtEpty As Long: NxtEpty = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

                'Use Union to combine the noncontinuous ranges in each row and paste to the next empty cell in the destination sheet
                Union(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 9)).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(NxtEpty, 1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```